# How to load an R package that exists locally on my hard disk?

Tags: r, package

If I have an R package that I've forked from another repo in a local location `~/mypkg`, is it possible to load directly from this location, without the need to use `install.packages`. The functionality I'm looking for is something like the `site.addsitedir` in Python.

I've tried several variations of:

```
library('mypkg', lib.loc = "/home/ncw135/Documents/mypkg")
```

and

```
devtools::load_all('/home/ncw135/Documents/mypgk')
```

which failed with:

```
Loading mypkg
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  cannot open file '/home/ncw135/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/mypkg/R/mypkg.rdb': No such file or directory
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

after trying to use one of their functions.

### addressing comments

The repo I want to make changes to is [here](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat)

Comment: (1) Is the repo you forked *from* publicly available, such as on GitHub? Having access to it could help others see what happens on their machine with `devtools::load_all()`. (2) I'm surprised `devtools::load_all()` didn't do it for you. I never use it, but I thought that was the purpose of the function. (3) Out of curiosity, what's the aversion to installing the package?

Comment: `devtools::load_all` doesn't work for me either.  It seems like a really bad idea:  why try to simulate installation without actually doing it, when installation is so easy?

Comment: @user2554330 Exactly, I have to wonder why not just install?

Comment: I'm just new to developing in R. Yes its a publically available repository (see edits). My thinking is that repeatedly installing and uninstalling after making changes seems like an inefficient way of doing things and was wondering if there was a better way. In Python, we just add the directory to the PythonPath using `site.addsitedir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't load a package without installing it.  If you don't want it permanently installed, you can set up a temporary library, install it there, and load from there as follows:

```
templib <- tempfile()
dir.create(templib)
.libPaths(templib)
install.packages("~/mypkg", lib = templib, type = "source", repos = NULL)
```

After that, `library(mypkg)` (using whatever package name is given in `~/mypkg/DESCRIPTION`) will load the temporarily installed package.  It will be deleted (along with any other packages you install after this into the same library) when you close the session and `templib` is automatically removed.  (It's possible `templib` will not be removed if your session crashes, but it won't be re-used in a future session.)

Comment: "No, you can't load a package without installing it." This is misleading; `devtools::load_all()` **should** simulate loading an uninstalled package very well. For proof, try `library(devtools); create_package("anRpackage", rstudio = FALSE, open = FALSE)`, then in `anRpackage/R/`, place a file `foo.R` containing `foo <- function(x) 2 * x`. Then try `load_all("anRpackage/"); foo(2)` -- you will see the expected output, `[1] 4`

Comment: That doesn't load the package, it simulates loading it. For some packages it doesn't work at all.  Even for your example, `ls(2)` doesn't list `"foo"`, as it would if I had installed the package and run `library(anRpackage)`:  the package ends up in 3rd place, not second place, and "exports" some junk functions that I didn't create.

Comment: This does work, but if I have to install and uninstall it everytime I want to test the new code in a project outside of the original, I might as well use the default package directory, right?

Comment: That's what I do.  If you're using RStudio or another helpful front end, it's no big deal to do an install.  There's never any need to uninstall as long as you restart R (which RStudio does automatically) so the package isn't loaded during an install.